# Apache: Is it possible to set a default custom log format to be used by all vhosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, virtualhost

I would like to set up custom logging for my vhosts in Apache 2.2:

What I'm looking for is a way to define a custom log format (once) that I can then use as the format for all of my vhost's configs custom logs.

Can I define the log format at the top of my vhost.conf file then refer to it within each vhost directive (Or do I define it in the main httpd.conf)? -- OR do I *have* to define it once for each vhost block?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking just for the log format definition in one place?

In your main server config, use the [LogFormat directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat):

```
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common
```

Note the end `vhost_common` is the nickname.

Then, you can specify in each vhost block to use that format for the log:

```
CustomLog logs/myvhost.access.log vhost_common
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Looked it up:

You can define a log format with the [`LogFormat`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) directive in your main config file and then use the [`CustomLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) statement inside your vHost files.

Also, at the very least you can include the same snippet defining your log format as an include into the config segment of each of your vHosts the same way you include those into the main httpd.conf. This is possible with every kind of configuration that is the same for many vHosts.